# Two variations of Python's main function

Tags: python

When writing scripts for personal use, I am used to doing this:

```
def do_something():
    # Do something.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_something()
```

Or, we can also do this:

```
def do_something(): 
    # Do something.  

do_something()      # No if __name__ thingy.
```

I know the first form is useful when differentiating between importing the script as a module or calling it directly, but otherwise for scripts that will only be executed (and never imported), is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Even if the script is only meant to be executed, it might sometimes be useful to import it anyway -- in an interactive shell, by documentation generation tools, in unit tests or to perform timings.  So routinely using the more general form will never hurt.

Answer (score 4):

The first form is just good practice.  One of the immutable laws of writing computer programs is that someone in the distant future (like right after you get assigned to another project or quit or get bored with maintaining the code) will want to use your "always standalone" script, or parts of it, for some other purpose.

If we assume that you are absolutely a rock-star programmer and that every character of your source files is saturated with genius (it is, right?), it makes sense that someone else will get an eyefull of your artwork and be simply knocked to the floor by your brilliance and will want to use it.

Now there's either the choice of making them cut-n-paste your code into a file with their name on the top, which is very un-DRY and makes the contribution of your extraordinary mind get credited to someone else, or you can just add that leetle bit of code and let them import your module and directly use the class or function that made them realize how very, very little they really knew about programming before they encountered it.

Your choice!

Comment: And, like Sven said, testing!